# Why $\int \limits _0 ^1 \log x \Bbb d x \ne \int \limits _0 ^{2 \pi} \log \sin x \Bbb d x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

From what I know integration is the summation of all infinitesimally small identical objects.
So won't the integration in both the cases be the sum of $\log(0), \dots, \log(1)$ because we're pretty much providing the same input to the logarithmic function?
According to Wolfram Alpha the results are different.

Comment: Probably you want $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log\sin x\,dx$

Comment: @egreg That integral gives $-\frac{1}{2}\pi\log(2)$, which is not $-1$ like the first one. (Assuming he meant $\log$ as $\ln$).

Comment: "summation of all infinitesimally small identical objects" Only defines integration of a constant.

Comment: @KimPeekII The function $\log\sin x$ is not even defined in the interval $(0,2\pi)$, so the second integral in the title makes no sense.

Comment: Anyway, you have discovered that integrals are not the sums of areas of infinitely thin rectangles.

Comment: @egreg Yes I actually meant that

Comment: @amalcade could you provide a link where I can read more about that?

Comment: @egreg wait..integrals aren't the sum of areas? Could you please elaborate more on that ?

Comment: @Dèsjardins Not in the naïve way you're thinking to them.

Comment: @egreg could you please point out where in my thinking am I going wrong?

Comment: @Dèsjardins You're thinking that those integrals are equal, but they aren't.

Comment: @egreg alright.... Thanks I guess

Comment: Essentially because $dx \neq d\sin x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will suppose that you want to understand why $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log\sin x\,dx \neq \int_{0}^{1}\log(x)\,dx$.

You are probably thinking that the integral should be the same because the values through which the function $f(x)=\log\sin x$ goes on the interval $[0, \pi/2]$ are the same as the values through which the function $g(x)=\log x$ goes on the interval $[0,1]$ and both functions are attaining the same values exactly once.

But if you look at the integral as the area of the curve (although in this two examples the area will be negative because graphs of the functions are below $x$-axis, but it does not matter for the discussion) then you have here two different curves, the curve $x\to (x,\log\sin x)$ on the interval $[0,\pi/2]$ and the curve $x\to (x,\log x)$ on the interval $[0,1]$ and although the $y$-coordinates of both curves will represent the same set of values the curves does not attain the same $y$-coordinate values at the equal $x$-coordinates (except $x=0$) so we are talking about two different curves so the integrals will also be different.

Comment: Well the x values wouldn't be equal but they would be equivalent (so to say) wouldn't they? Because for EVERY value of x in[0,1] which returns a certain value for log x  there would be an equivalent  value x in [0, π/2] for which log sinx would return the exact same value.  So yes if we were to plot the both the graphs on the same paper they would be a certain distance apart but I feel that the area under them should be the same (By the same logic that ive said above).

Comment: Wait but now that I think of it I realise that the 'width' of every y element would be different so the area would become different. Now I think I got it. Is the reasoning correct?

Comment: @Dèsjardins Well, it sounds like it is in the domain of "correctness" but you can crystallize it a bit more, I believe. The point further is that the interval $[0, \pi/2]$ is longer than the interval $[0,1]$ so we are integrating the curves with same set of $y$-coordinates, but the curves are different in the sense that the one is, to say it this way, more "stretched" than the other one, without going into the domain of how describe their difference the main point is that they are different. Is it a bit clearer now?

Comment: The width tends to $0$ in the process of integration so practically you should only realize that we are dealing with different curves.

Comment: Yes it's crystal clear now thank you very much.it was the width of the intervals actually that led me to this conclusion. Thanks alot :D

Answer (score 2):

Why should they be equal? You're integrating two very different curves:

These are your functions, clearly you're integrating something completely different.

[image]

But beyond this (because there are different functions whose integrals give the same results) the $\sin(x)$ functions behaves really different from the $x$ function.

When you integrate by substitutions, you have to take into account the so called **Jacobian** of the transformation which changes everything.

If you want, you can always try to solve this problem: "find those values $a$ and $b$ for which the integral of $\log(\sin(x))$ gives you $-1$".

**Hint**

$$\int_a^b \log\sin(x)\ \text{d} x = -x\log\left(1 - e^{2ix}\right) + x\log\left(\sin(x)\right) + \frac{1}{2}i\left(x^2 + \text{PolyLog}\left[2, e^{2ix}\right]\right)\bigg|_{a}^b$$

Answer (score 1):

If you are attempting a substitution, I think the substitution is wrong. Let $y=\sin(x)$. The integral limits become $0$ and $\sin(1)$. Then we get
\begin{equation*}
\int ^1_0 \ln(x)dx= \int^{\sin(1)}_{0} \frac{\ln(\sin(y))}{\cos(y)}dy.
\end{equation*}
If you integrate $\ln(x)$ from $0$ to $1$, we can use integration be parts to get $-1$ by treating $\ln(x)$ as $1\times \ln(x)$.

Comment: No its not really a substitution I'm talking about...

Comment: @Dèsjardins: In fact yes, it's a substitution that you are talking about, but you just do not realize this. What you are missing is that 1) $\sin$ is not bijective on $[0, 2\pi]$ (you plug each value *twice* in $\log$) and 2) there is also the Jacobian of the substitution to put inside the integral, which changes everything. The lesson to learn is that substitutions are not as intuitive as a newbie might expect, they have their quirks.

Comment: @AlexM. You might want to elaborate a bit on how what OP asks is really substitution, and why "the Jacobian of the substitution changes everything" (which is essentially the question).

Comment: @AlexM. I realise that between 0-2π all the elements would repeat twice that's why in the question I specified between 0-π/2. Also I don't really think this is a substitution, at least not in the conventional sense